# Adding multiple values to a key in python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary (d) who's keys are an id # and values are the wait time for each id.  For example

id:wait time

1:10

2:20

3:30

4:40

5:50

I need to compare each wait time to a service level and return either yes or no if the wait time met the service level to the dictionary.  So if the service level was 35 the new dictionary would look like

1:10,yes

2:20,yes

3:30,yes

4:40,no

5:50,no

I am having trouble getting the yes,no into the dictionary.  I can only override the wait time which I don't want.  Here is my current code

```
 for (key, val) in d.items():
        if val < sl:
              d[key] = 'Yes'
        else:
              d[key] = 'No'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain exactly what this: `10,yes` should be. As is it is not acceptable syntax. Are you looking to make it a list or a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (key, val) in d.items():
    if val < sl:
          d[key] = (val,'Yes')
    else:
          d[key] = (val,'No')
```

Or

```
for (key, val) in d.items():
    if val < sl:
          d[key] = (val,True)
    else:
          d[key] = (val,False)
```

If the `val` may be modified later , you can use `list` instead of `tuple`

Comment: Thank you.  That was simpler than I thought

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append Yes/no to the value of dictionary,else everything is fine:

```
for key,value in d.items():

if value<sl:
    d[key] = value +' Yes'    
else:
    d[key] = value +' No'
```